# How to gracefully shutdown a Go service running on Kubernetes

Tags: linux, docker, go, kubernetes, signals

I have an API written in Go that has been Dockerised and runs in a Kubernetes cluster on GKE.

At the moment my API server does not handle any shutdown scenarios such as a Pod dying or being purposefully brought down.

What set of UNIX signals should I expect to trap to gracefully shutdown the server and what circumstances would trigger them? For example, crashes, K8s shutdowns etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kubernetes sends a `SIGTERM` signal. So the graceful shutdown may look like this:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    var srv http.Server

    idleConnsClosed := make(chan struct{})
    go func() {
        sigint := make(chan os.Signal, 1)

        // interrupt signal sent from terminal
        signal.Notify(sigint, os.Interrupt)
        // sigterm signal sent from kubernetes
        signal.Notify(sigint, syscall.SIGTERM)

        <-sigint

        // We received an interrupt signal, shut down.
        if err := srv.Shutdown(context.Background()); err != nil {
            // Error from closing listeners, or context timeout:
            log.Printf("HTTP server Shutdown: %v", err)
        }
        close(idleConnsClosed)
    }()

    if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != http.ErrServerClosed {
        // Error starting or closing listener:
        log.Printf("HTTP server ListenAndServe: %v", err)
    }

    <-idleConnsClosed
}
```

Also you should add Liveness and Readiness probes to your pods:

```
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /health
    port: 80
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /health
    port: 80
```

Comment: What is the reason for the channel being buffered with make(chan os.Signal, 1)? I noticed it seems to work with an unbuffered channel i.e. make(chan os.Signal)

Answer (score 2):

Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54239385/12641885 only partly correct.
When Kubernetes send `SIGTERM` signal traffic can still route to the pod, because removing pod from endpoints set and `SIGTERM` signal is async - if pod is after `SIGTERM` endpoints may not have time to update.
`SIGTERM` only politely asks to start wrapping up, but don't stop accepting new requests at once.

You can add sleep into your code after `<-sigint` or add into your Deployment

```
lifecycle:
      preStop:
        exec:
          command: ["sh", "-c", "sleep 10"]
```

More detailed info https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/86280#issuecomment-583173036